# Editing XML node inner text only if has specified value

Tags: c#, xml, edit, editing

Hello i need your super help.
Im not soo skilled in C# and i stack for about 6 hours on this. So please if anyone know help me . Thx

I have Xml like this

```
<COREBASE>
  <AGENT>
    <AGENT_INDEX>1</AGENT_INDEX>
    <AGENT_PORTER_INDEX>
    </AGENT_PORTER_INDEX>
    <AGENT_NAME>John</AGENT_NAME>
    <AGENT_SURNAME>Smith</AGENT_SURNAME>
    <AGENT_MOBILE_NUMBER>777777777</AGENT_MOBILE_NUMBER>
 </AGENT>
  <AGENT>
    <AGENT_INDEX>2</AGENT_INDEX>
    <AGENT_PORTER_INDEX>1
    </AGENT_PORTER_INDEX>
    <AGENT_NAME>Charles</AGENT_NAME>
    <AGENT_SURNAME>Bukowski</AGENT_SURNAME>
    <AGENT_MOBILE_NUMBER>99999999</AGENT_MOBILE_NUMBER>
 </AGENT>
</COREBASE>
```

And I need to select agent by index in windows forms combo box and than edit and save his attributes to xml. I found how to edit and save it but i dont know why but its saved to the first agent and overwrite his attributes in XML but not in the selected one.. :-(

Plese i will be glad for any help

```
private void buttonEditAgent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument AgentBaseEdit = new XmlDocument();
    AgentBaseEdit.Load("AgentBase.xml");

    XDocument AgentBase = XDocument.Load("AgentBase.xml");

    var all = from a in AgentBase.Descendants("AGENT")
              select new
              {
                  agentI = a.Element("AGENT_INDEX").Value,
                  porterI = a.Element("AGENT_PORTER_INDEX").Value,
                  agentN = a.Element("AGENT_NAME").Value,
                  agentS = a.Element("AGENT_SURNAME").Value,
                  agentM = a.Element("AGENT_MOBILE_NUMBER").Value,

              };

    foreach (var a in all)
    {
        if ("" == textBoxEditAgentIndex.Text.ToString())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must fill Agent Index field !!", "WARNING");
        }
        else
        {
           // AgentBaseEdit.SelectSingleNode("COREBASE/AGENT/AGENT_INDEX").InnerText == textBoxEditAgentIndex.Text

            if (a.agentI == textBoxEditAgentIndex.Text.ToString())
            {
                AgentBaseEdit.SelectSingleNode("COREBASE/AGENT/AGENT_INDEX").InnerText = textBoxEditAgentIndex.Text;
                AgentBaseEdit.SelectSingleNode("COREBASE/AGENT/AGENT_PORTER_INDEX").InnerText = textBoxEditAgentPorterIndex.Text;
                AgentBaseEdit.SelectSingleNode("COREBASE/AGENT/AGENT_NAME").InnerText = textBoxEditAgentName.Text;
                AgentBaseEdit.SelectSingleNode("COREBASE/AGENT/AGENT_SURNAME").InnerText = textBoxEditAgentSurname.Text;
                AgentBaseEdit.SelectSingleNode("COREBASE/AGENT/AGENT_MOBILE_NUMBER").InnerText = textBoxEditAgentMobile.Text;

                AgentBaseEdit.Save("AgentBase.xml");
                ClearEditAgentTxtBoxes();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am i on the right way but i dont see the doors or i am totaly wrong ? Thx all. Miko

OK i tried it this way but it didnt changed the inner text

```
string agentIndex = comboBoxEditAgentI.SelectedItem.ToString();

        XmlDocument AgentBaseEdit = new XmlDocument();
        AgentBaseEdit.Load("AgentBase.xml");

        XDocument AgentBase = XDocument.Load("AgentBase.xml");

        var xElemAgent = AgentBase.Descendants("AGENT")
            .First(a => a.Element("AGENT_INDEX").Value == agentIndex);



        xElemAgent.Element("AGENT_MOBILE_NUMBER").Value = textBoxEditAgentMobile.Text;
        xElemAgent.Element("AGENT_SURNAME").Value = textBoxEditAgentSurname.Text;

        AgentBaseEdit.Save("AgentBase.xml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you use Linq2Xml.

```
int agentIndex = 2;

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

var xElemAgent = xDoc.Descendants("AGENT")
                .First(a => a.Element("AGENT_INDEX").Value == agentIndex.ToString());

//or
//var xElemAgent = xDoc.XPathSelectElement(String.Format("//AGENT[AGENT_INDEX='{0}']",agentIndex));

xElemAgent.Element("AGENT_MOBILE_NUMBER").Value = "5555555";

xDoc.Save(fileName)
```

PS: namespaces: `System.Xml.XPath` `System.Xml.Linq`

Comment: Hello thank you very mutch for help i tried your souliton but it doesnnt work for me after start debug i tried to edit agents surname and mobile i click save button and its seems like be ok but then i end the program go back to visual studio and it ask me if i want reload xml databse becouse it was modified from oustide program. for sure i pressed yes then look in database but inner text didnt changed. whats wrong with my code please ? you can see it up in my ask

Comment: var xElemAgent = xDoc.XPathSelectElement(String.Format("//AGENT[AGENT_INDEX='{0}']",agentIndex));
Even this doesnt work debug is succesull but after closing program im asked if i want reload xml overwrited items form other program but if i press yes nothing changes inside xml :-(

Comment: @user1936559 Did you save your xml back to disk after your edit? `xDoc.Save(fileName)`

Comment: AgentBaseEdit.Save("AgentBase.xml"); Yes like this :-(

Comment: @user1936559 I don't know how I can help you since the code I posted works well for me. You may have bugs in other parts of your code.

Comment: I think that code which you posted is what i was searching for! i hope that i will find out why it doesnt replace the inner text.. now is on me to find solution i just needed to find way thx very mutch i will tell if i will make it :-)

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEES MAN thx very mutch i found it ..:-)

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, because you are selecting the first agent explicitly with in each loop

```
AgentBaseEdit.SelectSingleNode("COREBASE/AGENT/...")
```

---

But you can do it easier by reading and changing withing the same xml document. I'm only changing the agent name and replacing it with "test 1", "test 2", ...

```
XDocument AgentBase = XDocument.Load("AgentBase.xml");
int i = 0;
foreach (XElement el in AgentBase.Descendants("AGENT")) {
    el.Element("AGENT_NAME").Value = "test " + ++i;
    // ...
}
AgentBase.Save("AgentBase.xml");
```

---

**UPDATE**

However, I'm suggesting you to separate the logic involving the XML handling from the form. Start by creating an Agent class

```
public class Agent
{
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string PorterIndex { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

Then create an interface defining the needed functionality for an agent repository. The advantage of this interface is that it will make it easier later to switch to another kind of repository like a relational database.

```
public interface IAgentRepository
{
    IList<Agent> LoadAgents();
    void Save(IEnumerable<Agent> agents);
}
```

Then create a class that handles the agents. Here is a suggestion:

```
public class AgentXmlRepository : IAgentRepository
{
    private string _xmlAgentsFile;

    public AgentXmlRepository(string xmlAgentsFile)
    {
        _xmlAgentsFile = xmlAgentsFile;
    }

    public IList<Agent> LoadAgents()
    {
        XDocument AgentBase = XDocument.Load(_xmlAgentsFile);
        var agents = new List<Agent>();
        foreach (XElement el in AgentBase.Descendants("AGENT")) {
            var agent = new Agent {
                Index = el.Element("AGENT_INDEX").Value,
                PorterIndex = el.Element("AGENT_PORTER_INDEX").Value,
                Name = el.Element("AGENT_NAME").Value,
                Surname = el.Element("AGENT_SURNAME").Value,
                Mobile = el.Element("AGENT_MOBILE_NUMBER").Value
            };
            agents.Add(agent);
        }
        return agents;
    }

    public void Save(IEnumerable<Agent> agents)
    {
        var xDocument = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
            new XElement("COREBASE",
                agents.Select(a =>
                    new XElement("AGENT",
                        new XElement("AGENT_INDEX", a.Index),
                        new XElement("AGENT_PORTER_INDEX", a.PorterIndex),
                        new XElement("AGENT_NAME", a.Name),
                        new XElement("AGENT_SURNAME", a.Surname),
                        new XElement("AGENT_MOBILE_NUMBER", a.Mobile)
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        xDocument.Save(_xmlAgentsFile);
    }
}
```

The form can now concentrate on the editing logic. The form does not even need to know what kind of repository to use if you inject the repository in the form constructor (of cause the form constructor must declare a parameter of type `IAgentRepository`):

```
var myAgentForm = new AgentForm(new AgentXmlRepository("AgentBase.xml"));
myAgentForm.Show();
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

Note that you cannot change a single item within an XML file. You must load all the agents, make an edit and then rewrite the whole file, even if you edited only one agent.

To do this, you can use my `LoadAgents` method, then pick an agent from the returned list, edit the agent and finally write the agents list back to the file with my `Save` method. You can find an agent in the list with LINQ:

```
Agent a = agents
    .Where(a => a.Index == x)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This returns `null` if an agent with the required index does not exist. Since `Agent` is a reference type, you don’t have to write it back to the list. The list is keeping a reference to the same agent as the variable `a`.

Comment: Hello thx for help! But your first answer solving automaticly generated index but this index must be writen by user, than after some time he might will need change it. The index of agent will be fixed forever but attributes like mobile number or name might be nesecary to change one day. So i need code which will find agent which index will be selected somewhere... than change his nodes values and save in at selected agent index. Maybe im stupid but i dont see method which will replace agent values depending on his index value ...

Comment: I already know how to replace agent parametrs but problem is that replaced agent is first in xml in need to select agent in database (depending on his index) which will be replaced... But your code is genial becouse it will help me a lot in a future becouse in will need to generate new xml file which will become from COREBASE and xml with values for each month so i will probably use something like u writen. Thx a lot and if you know how to select agent (just specific agent depending on selected index in form) from database and replace his values please let me know.

Comment: Select a specific agent like this. Let's assume that you want agent no 7: `XElement el = AgentBase.Descendants("AGENT").Where(e => e.Element("AGENT_INDEX").Value == "7").FirstOrDefault();
if (el == null) return null; return new Agent { ... };`